# ISPConfig 3, a ninja sets my open_basedir

Tags: php, linux, apache, open-basedir

I have a PHP library that I'd like to share to several vhosts on my server, but the open_basedir directive is causing troubles.

I use ISPConfig 3 to manage the sites.

> **PHP Warning**:  include(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/var/toaster/latest/__server/core/cms.php) is not within the
>   allowed path(s): (*[cut:several paths]*) in *[cut]* on line 5

### phpinfo() says:

> **Loaded Configuration File**: /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
>   **open_basedir**: *[cut:several paths]* (local & master value)

### /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini says:

> ;open_basedir =

### /usr/local/ispconfig/server/conf/vhost.conf.master says:

> <tmpl_if name='security_level' op='==' value='20'>
>       php_admin_value open_basedir <tmpl_var name='php_open_basedir'>
>   </tmpl_if>

### but /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/[cut: domain].vhost says:

absolutely nothing about open_basedir

---

All this means that something unknown to me sets my open_basedir directive. What, Where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was much easier and obvious than expected.
In the "Options" panel of the "Web Domain" in ISPConfig there is a textbox labeled `PHP open_basedir`. I still don't know which exact config file that is going to create or edit, but it works.

Also worth mentioning for this textbox - the default value when creating a new site can be changed in:

System >> Server Config >> Web >> PHP Settings >> PHP open_basedir

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much for the answer! I looked everywhere, and the answer was right there on the options screen! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

After further investigation, ISPConfig executes php-cgi when a vhost starts. The starter script is in /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web?/.php-fcgi-starter, where the ? represents the site number within the client. The open_basedir is passed as a parameter to the startup. That's why overriding in the individual php.ini doesn't work. At least, that's how it's configured when the site is fast-cgi / su-exec.

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment, for some reason the input field in the **ispconfig panel** (PHP open_basedir @ PHP settings) would not update. By editing the **.php-fcgi-starter** file I was able to add a location.